trace cookie creation in browser devtools
I'm trying to understand a website's login process
After I login, it creates a cookie but I can't find out which code is creating this cookie
I used firefox devTools and I can see that after posting data to login page the next request contains that specific cookie but none of the previous request's responses have any header to create that cookie
I searched for document.cookie in every js file, and set breakpoint on every line but none of them triggered for that cookie creation
I injected this code in console before login, but still no luck
origDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Document.prototype, 'cookie');
Object.defineProperty(document, 'cookie', {
  get() {
    return origDescriptor.get.call(this);
  },
  set(value) {
    debugger;
    return origDescriptor.set.call(this, value);
  },
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});

The website is written with angular I guess (ng-version="17.0.8")
Is there any other way to create cookies? I'm a web developer myself and I've always thought that it's only possible to create cookie through js and http response headers
P.S: I was googling around and saw some posts about firebug and the ability to create breakpoint on cookie creation but it seems it's replaced by firefox dev edition and this one doesn't have that ability

Was the cookie absent from all previous requests, or was it perhaps already in the browser when you started?

before the login it's absent, after the login it's magically there

I just realized that there's a bug with firefox dev edition, it doesn't show this cookie in http response headers and it was making me confused

if the server creates the cookie via the response header, JS will know nothing about that.  (even if the JS receives the subsequent response... things like set cookie header are sent first... browser responds back when cookie is written)  You can view detailed requests/responses in Network tab of dev tools.  Right-click on the request and choose, "Copy All as HAR file".  Paste into notepad to view it.

As far as I know, the DevTools currently don't offer a simple way to see the origin of a cookie. Therefore, I've created a feature request for the Firefox DevTools many years ago.
And while there is no direct way to see the origin of a cookie, you can still find out about where it got set.
You're right that cookies can only be set via HTTP headers or within JavaScript. And your approach is correct for the case the cookie is set via document.cookie.
Though be aware that you need to set that code on the very first JavaScript statement to catch all cases in which cookies are set.
To do that, the Firefox and Chrome DevTools have an option to stop the script execution at the first statement in the Event Listener Breakpoints pane within the Debugger/Sources panel called Script > Script First Statement.

Note that besides document.cookie there is also a newer Cookie Store API, which allows to set cookies via cookieStore.set(). So you may also intercept calls to that API if it exists to see whether a cookie is set that way.
To find out whether the cookie is set via a response header instead, both the Firefox and the Chrome DevTools provide a filter within their Network panel to do that.
This filter is called set-cookie-name:. Once you've entered that, there's already an auto-completion for all the cookies set, though you can also explicitly enter the name of the cookie you're searching for.
In Chrome that looks like this:

In Firefox the filter looks like this:

Important for this is that you preserve the requests log across page loads. So, before you login, you need to set the Persist Logs option in the Firefox DevTools, which is available within the settings menu of the Network panel

In the Chrome DevTools' Network panel this option is called Preserve log and is located in the options bar.

Those features should allow you to find out how the cookie is set.
